# What is the best way to get data from url and parse it on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-tagsoup

I'm having trouble with parsing data from url.

I have url with "https://" so i think i should use import Network.HTTP.Conduit
But

```
simpleHttp url
```

returns L.ByteString
I really don't understand what shoud i do after that

So i have such code to get data

```
toStrict1 :: L.ByteString -> B.ByteString
toStrict1 = B.concat . L.toChunks

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lbs <- simpleHttp url
    let page = toStrict1 lbs
```

and example of parsing

```
    let lastModifiedDateTime = fromFooter $ parseTags doc
    putStrLn $ "wiki.haskell.org was last modified on " ++ lastModifiedDateTime
    where fromFooter = unwords . drop 6 . words . innerText . take 2 . dropWhile (~/= "<li id=footer-info-lastmod>")
```

How can i combine this two parts of code?

Comment: You could use [**`scalpel`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel-0.6.0). I personally find it a rather convenient way to parse HTML. It is a library that has the same scope as `BeautifulSoup` in Python, but of course more declarative and type safe :).

Comment: tagsoup is another option.

Comment: Why define `toStrict1` when [`toStrict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toStrict) is already available in the library?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard yes, I plan to use tagsoup. but I will need to parse the list with nested objects, there are no actual examples in the documentation. maybe you know where can i find such?
`toStrict1` is my mistake, thanks:)
i even dont know now what to do with this ByteString...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, the `simpleHttp` function returns a lazy bytestring.  There are several ways to deal with this in TagSoup.

First, it turns out that you can parse it directly.  The function `parseTags` has signature:

```
parseTags :: StringLike str => str -> [Tag str]
```

meaning that it can parse any type `str` with a `StringLike` instance, and if you look at the `Text.StringLike` module documentation, you'll see that lazy `ByteStrings` have a `StringLike` instance.

However, if you go this route, you need to be aware that everything's kind of "trapped" in a `ByteString` world, so you have to write your code using versions of functions like `words` and `unwords` that are bytestring-compatible, and even your `putStrLn` needs an adapter.  A full working example would look like this:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as CL

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lbs <- simpleHttp "https://wiki.haskell.org"
    let lastModifiedDateTime = fromFooter $ parseTags lbs
    putStrLn $ "wiki.haskell.org was last modified on " 
        ++ CL.unpack lastModifiedDateTime
    where fromFooter = CL.unwords . drop 6 . CL.words
              . innerText . take 2 . dropWhile (~/= "<li id=footer-info-lastmod>")
```

and it works fine:

```
> main
wiki.haskell.org was last modified on 9 September 2013, at 22:38.
>
```

The functions from `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` basically assume that the bytestring is ASCII-encoded, which is close enough for this example to work.

However, it would be more robust to decode the bytestring based on the proper character encoding to a valid text type.  The two main text types in Haskell are the default `String` type, which is inefficient and slow, but easy to work with, and the `Text` type, which is highly efficient but a bit more complicated.  (Like `ByteString`, you need to use `Text`-compatible versions of functions like `words` and so on.)  Both `String` and `Text` have `StringLike` instances, so they both work fine with TagSoup.

If we were going to write production-quality code, we'd actually consult the response headers from the HTTP request and/or check for a `<meta>` tag in the HTML to determine the real encoding.  But, if we just assume the coding is UTF-8 (which it is), the `Text` version looks like this:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as TL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lbs <- simpleHttp "https://wiki.haskell.org"
    let lastModifiedDateTime = fromFooter $ parseTags (TL.decodeUtf8 lbs)
    putStrLn $ "wiki.haskell.org was last modified on " 
        ++ TL.unpack lastModifiedDateTime
    where fromFooter = TL.unwords . drop 6 . TL.words
              . innerText . take 2 . dropWhile (~/= "<li id=footer-info-lastmod>")
```

and a `String` version using `Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8` from the `utf8-string` package looks like this:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 as BL

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lbs <- simpleHttp "https://wiki.haskell.org"
    let lastModifiedDateTime = fromFooter $ parseTags (BL.toString lbs)
    putStrLn $ "wiki.haskell.org was last modified on " 
        ++ lastModifiedDateTime
    where fromFooter = unwords . drop 6 . words
              . innerText . take 2 . dropWhile (~/= "<li id=footer-info-lastmod>")
```